# Error: Unable to find module with ID: welcome when using aurelia-cli webpack with the skeleton-nav

Tags: aurelia

I have copied the skeleton-navigation to the base install of an aurelia-cli webpack project and am getting Error: Unable to find module with ID: welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got the moduleId set like this with a PLATFORM.moduleName(...) ?

```
config.map([
          { route: ['', 'welcome'], name: 'welcome', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('./welcome'), nav: true, title: 'Welcome' },
```

Comment: Yes I reported this as a bug because it only happens when you remove the user's route, I know it sounds strange but here is the bug report https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/859

Answer (score 0):

**for typescript**  for this you need to add following import

**import { Aurelia, PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-framework';**

```
   router: Router;
  configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router): void {
    this.router = router;
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.map([        
      { route: '123', name: 'index123', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('./index'), title:"index" }         
    ]);
  }
```